# Form an numpy array from indices and fill with zeroes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a nympy array `a = np.array([483, 39, 18, 999, 20, 48]`

I have an array of indices `indices = np.array([2, 3])`

I would like to have all the indices of the array and fill the rest of the indices with 0 so I get as a result :

`np.array([0, 0, 18, 999, 0, 0])`

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create an all zeros array and copy the values at the desired indices:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([483, 39, 18, 999, 20, 48])
indices = np.array([2, 3])

b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[indices] = a[indices]

# a = b     # if needed

print(a)
print(indices)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[483  39  18 999  20  48]
[2 3]
[  0   0  18 999   0   0]
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** Even better, use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([483, 39, 18, 999, 20, 48])
indices = np.array([2, 3])

print(a)
print(indices)

a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(a.shape[0]), indices, True)] = 0

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[483  39  18 999  20  48]
[2 3]
[  0   0  18 999   0   0]
```

Comment: `setdiff1d` is probably going to be slower, particularly for large arrays, since it has to sort and perform binary searches instead of just going straight to the indices it needs.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree. In this specific case, one might want to set `assume_unique = True` (I added that in my answer) to get some speedup.

Answer (score -1):

What about using list comprehension?

```
a = np.array([n if i in indices else 0 for i, n in enumerate(a)])

print(a) #array([  0,   0,  18, 999,   0,   0])
```

Comment: This has the same problems as Matheus's answer.

Comment: Speed was not a constrain here. I find the downvote eccessive since the answer is technically correct and gives the desired result.

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out in the comments of my answer as well, it doesn't seem to make sense to downvote a **correct** answer only for the efficiency matter, even more since it was never mentioned in the original question in the first place.

Comment: Unless you're working on computability theory, speed is always a constraint. Something that doesn't finish until next year is going to be downvoted if it could have been done in a minute.

Comment: @user2357112 the OP is asking how to convert an array of lenght 6. It doesn't say anything else. Speed is not a constrain in this case, like in many other cases. Everybody would do array computation in Fortran otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a function that uses the input array and the index array to do this, as in the following:

```py
import numpy as np

def remove_by_index(input_array, indexes):
    for i,_ in enumerate(input_array):
        if i not in indexes:
            input_array[i] = 0
    return input_array

input_array = np.array([483, 39, 18, 999, 20, 48])
indexes = np.array([2, 3])

new_out = remove_by_index(input_array, indexes)

expected_out = np.array([0, 0, 18, 999, 0, 0])

print(new_out == expected_out)  # to check if it's correct
```

### **Edit**

You can also use list comprehension inside the function, which would be better, as:

```py
def remove_by_index(input_array, indexes):
    return [input_array[i] if (i in indexes) else 0 for i,_ in enumerate(input_array)]
```

It is **not**, as pointed out in comments, the most efficient way of doing it, performing iteration at Python level instead of C level, but it does work, and for casual use it will solve.

Comment: This is extremely slow, performing iteration at Python level instead of C level, and scanning the whole `indexes` array for an `in` check on every iteration of the Python `for` loop (and yes, [it really is scanning the *whole* `indexes` array](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cbced22a8306d7214a4e18d12e651c034143922/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c#L114), with no early exit if a match is found, though an early exit wouldn't help much).

Comment: Yes, you are correct when speaking of efficiency, but since OP didn't mention performance issues and it is a simple solution, it seems adequate (and it is effective), it does answer the question correctly.